# How can I cons the result of two different list filters?

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a list of Objects of type Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int).I am trying to filter through a List of leaves and insert a new leaf so that the list of Leaves is ordered by weight. The new Leaf gets its values from a list of Pairs that I am iterating through

```
  def makeOrderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[Leaf] = {

  def orderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)], leaves: List[Leaf] ): List[Leaf] = {
    freqs match  {
      //Problem on line below
      case head::tail => orderedLeafList(tail, leaves.filter( _.weight < head._2) :: Leaf(head._1, head._2) :: leaves.filter( _.weight > head._2)) 
      case _ => leaves
    }
  }
orderedLeafList(freqs,  List())
}
```

The problem I get on the specified line is **Type mismatch, expected List[Huffman.Leaf], actual: List[Product with Serializable]** when I try to cons the results of the filters. I should be able to cons the result of a filter should I not? I'm new to scala but have done functional programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:::` instead of `::` to concatenate two lists. `::` combines an `X` with a `List[X]`.

```
def makeOrderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[Leaf] = {

  def orderedLeafList(freqs: List[(Char, Int)], leaves: List[Leaf] ): List[Leaf] = {
    freqs match  {
      //Problem on line below
      case head::tail => orderedLeafList(tail, leaves.filter( _.weight < head._2) ::: Leaf(head._1, head._2) :: leaves.filter( _.weight > head._2)) 
      case _ => leaves
    }
  }
  orderedLeafList(freqs,  List())
}
```

The reason you get that strange error message is that you *can* actually add a `List[Leaf]` as a single element to the head of a `List[Leaf]` and get something like: `List(List(leaf1, leaf2), leaf3, leaf4, leaf5)`. The resulting type is the common supertype of `Leaf` and `List[Leaf]`, which is `Product with Serializable`.